# How to plot grouped columns along the x-axis in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with three columns. `City`, `State`, and `Sales`.

To retrieve the total `Sales` for each city I use:

```
df.groupby(['City','State']).sum()[['Sales']]
```

Because I must be able to differenciate between cities of the same name, `State` needs to be included as well. Now, my question is, how can I group `City` and `State` along the x-axis and put `Sales` on the y-axis on a Matplotlib bar graph? I could just concatinate the `City` and `State` into its own column and then plot that new column on the x-axis. I find that somewhat sloppy though. What would the code look like to get the `City` and `State` together on the x-axis (without creating a new column). I want it to look something like the picture below.
I appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df.groupby(['City', 'State']).sum().plot.bar(xlabel='City', ylabel='Sales')
```

[image]

Comment: Oh nice. That actually works out nicely. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a column name, with str, then groupby it, then plot, as simple as that...

```py
df['Name'] = df['City'] + ' (' + df['State']) + ')'
df.groupby(['Name']).sum()[['Sales']].plot()
```

Comment: I could do that. Is there a way to do it without creating a new column?

Comment: Yes, you could transform list(df['City'] + ' (' + df['State']) + ')) and then passing it to the plot as labels, but then you'll have to use matplotlib more in details... https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py